# Fill missing days in data

Tags: php, time

I have an array which looks like this:

```
$data = array(
    array('timestamp' => 1312776000, 'something' => 100), // data for 08.08.2011
    array('timestamp' => 1312862400, 'something' => 120), // data for 09.08.2011
    //  ????????                                          // data for 10.08.2011
    array('timestamp' => 1313035200, 'something' => 160), // data for 11.08.2011
    array('timestamp' => 1313121600, 'something' => 180), // data for 12.08.2011
    array('timestamp' => 1313208000, 'something' => 200), // data for 13.08.2011
    //  ????????                                          // data for 14.08.2011
    //  ????????                                          // data for 15.08.2011
    //  ????????                                          // data for 16.08.2011
    //  ????????                                          // data for 17.08.2011
    array('timestamp' => 1313640000, 'something' => 300), // data for 18.08.2011
);
```

How to identify "holes" and fill them with a subarray with 'something' => 0? As you can see, "holes" can be very large, that is why i was not able to solve this problem myself - my algorithm can fill only tiny "holes" (like 10.08.2011, but not 14.08.2011 -> 17.08.2011).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to consider:

```
$previous_d = false;
for($di=0; isset($data[$di]); $di++) {
    $d = $data[$di];
    if($previous_d && ($d['timestamp']-$previous_d['timestamp'])>86400) {
        $new_d = array('timestamp'=>$previous_d['timestamp']+86400,'something'=>0);
        array_splice($data,$di,0,array($new_d));
        $di--;
    }
    $previous_d = $d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data appears to be sorted, and I'm guessing you want a single value per day.  I've taken the lazy approach of writing a new output array, but you could append values to the existing array, and then sort by timestamp at the end.

I'd do something like this:

```
$outArray = array();
$lastTime = $data[0]['timestamp'] - 86400;
foreach($data as $values) {
    $dayDelta = ($values['timestamp'] - $lastTime)/86400;
    if ( $dayDelta != 1) {
        for ($i = $dayDelta-1; $i--; $i>0) {
            $pastDate = $values['timestamp'] - $i * 86400;
            $outArray[] = array('timestamp'=>$pastDate, 'something'=>0);
        }
    }
    $outArray[]=$values;
    $lastTime = $values['timestamp'];
}
```

Comment: There is a much shorter solution I think. Will try to write it down.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way:

```php
$new = array();
$prev = reset($data);
while ($record = reset($data)) {
    while ($prev['timestamp'] < $record['timestamp']-86400) {
        $prev['timestamp'] += 86400;
        $prev['something'] = 0;
        $new[] = $prev;
    }
    $new[] = $record;
    $prev = $record;
    unset($data[key($data)]);
}
$data = $new;

echo '<pre>';
var_export($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Yes, you are right 'something' increases linearly. But it is just an example and I've made the sample data look like that just for fun. Real data (number of website visiors or adsense revenue) can not be predicted, so your method will not work.

Comment: Ok, updated the code, so now it insert also zero to 'something' :-)